# Understanding how "by" works as a delegate

Tags: kotlin

The following code shows a delegate:

```
override val vm: MyViewModel by viewModel()

inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> LifecycleOwner.viewModel(
    key: String? = null,
    name: String? = null,
    noinline parameters: ParameterDefinition = emptyParameterDefinition()
) = viewModelByClass(T::class, key, name, null, parameters)
```

I don't really understand what is happening when you have `by viewModel`

Does viewModel() cause the inline function to be called and its return value assigned to the variable vm?

Comment: If you haven't already read it, check out [Delegated Properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html).

Comment: Yeah, I read that but it isn't clear. For example, the very first paragraph in that document says: "The expression after by is the delegate, because get() (and set()) corresponding to the property will be delegated to its getValue() and setValue() methods." - Yet in the code I posted above, there are no getValue(0 and setValue() methods, not even in further levels of the call hierarchy. Hence the poor documentation.

Comment: Well, `viewModel(...)` calls another function, `viewModelByClass(...)`. Eventually a class/interface is returned which will have defined a `getValue(...)` method and a possible `setValue(...)` method which the property's `get` method and possible `set` method delegates to, respectively.

Comment: As I mentioned, there is no getValue() or setValue() methods in the hierarchy. You can open up Android Studio and navigate a viewModel and you won't come across one.

Comment: Alright, assuming this is `koin-androidx-viewmodel` then `viewModel(...)` calls `viewModelByClass(..)` which in turn calls [`lazy(...)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/lazy.html) which returns an instance of `Lazy`. There is an extension operator function for `Lazy`: [`getValue(...)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/get-value.html). That's the method being delegated to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `inline` function just creates a new instance of `MyViewModel` and the getter / setter gets delegated to it. In your code the `inline` function is necessary because it uses a `reified` type parameter which you use in

```
viewModelByClass(T::class, key, name, null, parameters) // note the T::class
```

What happens in this line:

```
override val vm: MyViewModel by viewModel()
```

is that a `MyViewModel` gets created by calling `viewModel()` and its `Property` is assigned to the `vm` field. The `by` keyword works by means of [Operator Overloading](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html). In this case the operators in question are:

```
operator fun getValue(thisRef: R, property: KProperty<*>): T
```

and

```
public operator fun setValue(thisRef: R, property: KProperty<*>, value:
```

If you implement these in any class you'll be able to use it as a property delegate.

I've written about this topic in depth [here](https://the-cogitator.com/posts/blog/2018/09/29/by-the-way-exploring-delegation-in-kotlin.html#property-delegation) if you want more clarification.

Comment: So are you saying Kotlin implicitly creates (behind-the-scenes) the methods getValue and setValue when it sees the "by" operator?

Comment: No, it is present in `MyViewModel` or one of its superclases. Everything is explicit. `by` only works if there is a `getValue` and / or `setValue`.

Comment: In Android Studio, I went through the superclasses and did not find any getValue or setValue methods.